# How to remove a user from jail with Jailkit?

Tags: user-management

I have created a jail with Jailkit and jailed a user.

However, after looking on the [Jailkit description](http://olivier.sessink.nl/jailkit/jailkit.8.html), I still cannot find a command to unjail the user.

How do I do that?

Answer (score 1):

```
jk_jailuser - a utility to put an existing user in a jail
```

This seems to be true, it doesn't give you any option to remove a user from the jail.

Let us see what happens when you jail a user. Example:

To jail user jane, you use the command
`jk_jailuser -m -j /home/jail jane`.
The entry for user jane in /etc/passwd will be changed to this:

```
jane:x:1016:1016::/home/jail/./home/jane:/usr/sbin/jk_chrootsh
```

To unjail user jane you need to change the entry in `/etc/passwd`

I can't know how your original entry looked like, so here an example for the entry of my own account in
`/etc/passwd`:

```
mook:x:1000:1000:Mook,,,:/home/mook:/bin/bash
```

Here some additional information about the syntax for entries in `/etc/passwd`

```
jane:x:1021:1020:Jane,,,:/home/jane:/bin/bash
____ _ ____ ____ _______ __________ _________
 1   2  3    4      5        6         7

1:  Username: It is used when user logs in. It should be between
    1 and 32 characters in length.
2:  Password: An x character indicates that encrypted password
    is stored in /etc/shadow file.
3:  User ID (UID): Each user must be assigned a user ID (UID).
    UID 0 (zero) is reserved for root and UIDs 1-99 are reserved
    for other predefined accounts. Further UID 100-999 are reserved by
    system for administrative and system accounts/groups.
4:  Group ID (GID): The primary group ID (stored in /etc/group file)
5:  User ID Info: The comment field. It allow you to add extra information
    about the users such as user’s full name, phone number etc. This field
    use by finger command.
6:  Home directory: The absolute path to the directory the user will be in
    when they log in.If this directory does not exists then users directory
    becomes /.
7:  Command/shell: The absolute path of a command or shell (/bin/bash).
    Typically, this is a shell.Please note that it does not have to be
    a shell.
```

After editing the entry in `/etc/passwd` correctly, your user should be free...

Comment: Yes and NO.
Yes, because if you remove the user-directory from jail and remove the passwd-entry in `/etc/passwd` of the jail the user can't login anymore...
But NO, because if you try to add a new user with the same name, you got some notices from jailkit, that this user still exist. (see: https://superuser.com/questions/1679028/remove-a-user-from-jailkit) 
It seems to be there are also other places where jailkit save information about user-accounts.